# Can TensorBoard or other tools visualize TensorFlow.js models?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow.js

In https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load, it describes the format for saving model files as one that uses `model.json` and the corresponding `model.weights.bin`.  I'm not sure if there's a name for talking about this format (I think it's the same as https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#class:LayersModel but not entirely certain), and I'm wondering if there's a way to visualize them as a graph.

I was expecting to be able to load and view them in TensorBoard but don't see any way to do this with its "Graphs" tool, so perhaps no one has made anything like this yet.

Answer (score 0):

One minimal way to do this is with the [summary](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers) method on a loaded model, which will log to the console:

[image]

In the example I tried, this output doesn't match what I would expect from looking at the `model.json` though.  It looks like this might only look at the outermost Sequential layer but I didn't look more closely.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine models, layers and tensors and etc via `Visor API` https://js.tensorflow.org/api_vis/latest/. You just need to install it `npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-vis` in order to use.